# Hardening Homemade Butterscotch into the Consistency of Butterscotch Chips

Tags: baking

I've been considering making butterscotch chip cookies with homemade butterscotch chips for a while now, but every time I look for recipes I find only butterscotch sauce recipes or recipes that **use** butterscotch chips.

So, assuming I've made butterscotch sauce, how would I go about properly hardening it to make chips or chunks out of it?

Comment: Welcome to the site thepocketwade. Please take some time to familiarize yourself with the rules noted in our [FAQ](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq). Recipe requests are not appropriate here.

Comment: welcome!  Recipe requests are considered off-topic for this site (see the FAQ: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq).  An interesting question that would be on-topic would be along the lines of "how could I convert <homemade white chocolate chips/butterscotch sauce/something else> into butterscotch chips?" or "What methods could I use to harden butterscotch into a chocolate consistency?"

Comment: Fair enough, how's this edit work, or do I still need to change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This page](http://www.yelp.com/topic/san-francisco-hot-dessert-talk-2-homemade-butterscotch-chips--how) suggests mixing the butterscotch sauce in to white chocolate, which makes sense to me. You need something that will be solid at room temperature.

Comment: This is what I would do as well.